# Maven build - Given path to java executor does not exist "C:\somepath\jdk\zulujdk-11\bin\java"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am building my project using maven in Intellij. I am getting the following error :

> Given path to java executor does not exist "C:\somepath\jdk\zulujdk-11\bin\java"

Don't pay much attention to the exact path. My issue is that I was using this path previously but now, I have changed it to jdk 17 in all configurations in intellij and environment variables. Yet I am getting this error.
I have changed the configurations in Intellij in,

1. Under project structure -> project. Both SDK and language level are at 17.
2. Under modules , all the modules are using the project SDK.
3. In settings, Under Build Execution and Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven , then under Importing and Runner, both are using the project SDK.

I have seen almost everywhere and cannot seem to find where that previous path is being mentioned. I have invalidated cache and restarted the IDE as well. Please help, if I need to change the settings some where else or any other changes I need to do.

Comment: Does it work from the command line?

Comment: How do you trigger the build? IDEA has a few options and some rely on its' own Build System, not Maven. You can also try to download a fresh JDK copy via IDEA or re-add the existing one with Project Structure -> SDKs

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It does. If I run "mvn clean install" , it works in that directory from cmd. But from Intellij , in the same path, it's not working.

Comment: @romanv-jb Not exactly sure about that. But I am triggering it in maven view on the right side. Under Lifecycle in my component, there is clean and install. So I am running. It does show me the run configurations and in those also, I have chosen jdk 17 under Java options.

Comment: Might be the simplest to delete the .idea folder and reopen the project in intellij.  Perhaps even reclone it

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yeah probably, I will try

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen deleting the .idea folder did not work. I deleted the entire folder and recloned the repo. Now it works. But I still have no idea why it did.